# Liquibase: execute change sets within a change log as different a different user

Tags: maven, liquibase

Does anyone know if it is possible to execute change sets within a change log as different a different user?

For instance:

```
ChangeSetID 1, run as user DBA
ChangeSetID 2, run as user TABLE_OWNER
ChangeSetID 3, run as user DBA
```

I have tried using the `<preConditions>` tag with `<runningAs>` and `<dbms>` without any avail

I am only using maven to run the database migration, and am not running a spring app or anything like that with liquibase

Answer (score 0):

The [preconditions](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html) are just meant to verify certain conditions before the changeset will run.

Liquibase is just running your changeset and changing users falls on the orchestration outside of liquibase.

Comment: yep, we've found the better solution is to write explicit schema specific scirpts and permission the DBA user to make changes to other schemas